# How i can pipe image file to upload endpoint with superagent?

Tags: node.js, superagent

```
/**
 *  Request png
 */
 var request = require('superagent')
 var req = request.get('http://example.com/original/' + id + '.png');

 req.end(function(response){
   // Here i want send responsed image to another server
   req.post('http://upload-example.com').attach('???')
 })
```

How i can pipe image file to upload endpoint?
I use latest version of superagent in nodejs env.

Answer (score 2):

`attach` can set Buffer.
But, you need to use `filename` option.

this works well.

```
var request = require('superagent');
request.get('https://example.com/image.png')
  .end((err, res) => {
    // Here i want send responsed image to another server
    console.log(err, res.body); // body is Buffer
    request.post('http://upload-example.com')
      .attach('image', res.body, {filename: 'test.png'})
      .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(err, res.statusCode);
      });
});
```